# How to stop incredibuild from auto-installation on my PC?

Tags: visual-studio, incredibuild

It seems that incredibuild was installed on my PC, likely came in bundle with visual studio. It autostarts when my PC runs, and it has high disk usage and eventually will slow down the entire PC. I will have to stop it from running to make my PC fast again.

I tried removing it but each time I did, it would come back a few days later even if I havent used visual studio for the past 2 weeks. Disabling it from startup will not work either, it will be running when the PC starts anyway. So what am I supposed to do with Incredibuild? I dont want to uninstall Visual Studio, but I need Incredibuild gone.

Comment: this thing is like virus. never seen worse programmed application. i have uninstalled it completely and there are still services remained running in the background caused my PC to freeze a few times.

Answer (score 2):

IncrediBuild is a build acceleration software that accelerates Visual Studio compilations by distributing the compilation tasks to idle machines across your network. As IncrediBuild is bundled with Visual Studio, you probably chose to install it as part of your Visual Studio setup.
IncrediBuild is not supposed to use any of your resources when it is not in use and we haven't received such a feedback from the >100,000 developer using IncrediBuild...
To uninstall the IncrediBuild plug-in, go to Visual Studio Tools->Extensions and Updates. In the popup window, under the Install tab, choose IncrediBuild Build Acceleration and uninstall. 
We'd highly appreciate if you can make sure that the problem you reported indeed comes from IncrediBuild and if so, contact us at support@incredibuild.com

Disclaimer, the write is working at IncrediBuild.

Comment: It happens again that incredibuild is slowing down my PC with ridiculous disk usage. http://oi65.tinypic.com/20i9fo7.jpg

Comment: Can you please make sure you are running the latest version of IncrediBuild? We don't have any such open reports...    I urge you again to reach our support in order for us to make sure the issue you experience is addressed, this may be an environment \ anti virus issue... Disclaimer, the write is working at IncrediBuild.

Comment: @Dori - I have the same issue, and I just want it gone. I don't ever want to have to go through the extended nightmare of having to uninstall Incredibuld every single time I restart my computer. At this point, It's a virus, not a helper.

Comment: Hi Michiel, we assume that the reason you have this problem is due to the fact that IncrediBuild was installed from the Visual Studio installer but you tried to remove it using the Add / Remove programs or the regular setup “uninstall” option.
Like other extensions that are installed from the Visual Studio installer – in order to remove them you must do it from the Visual Studio -> Extensions -> Manage Extensions menu. 
 
IncrediBuild isn't installed automatically with VS as this option in unchecked by default, please mail us directly to support@incredibuild.com if the problem persists.

Comment: @Michieal if you check the services, there are services remaining even you completely uninstall it.

Comment: @Dori You're right. And VS Kept reinstalling it for me. Since, I never allow it to be installed by VS Setup.

Comment: I get the error below from vs manage extensionss:

"no matching workload or component found"